# Number of threads used by rails puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I have a rails application running with puma server. Is there any way, we can see how many number of threads used in application currently ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Puma, how to know the number of active threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862767/puma-how-to-know-the-number-of-active-threads)

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about the same thing a while ago and came upon this [issue](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/811). The author included the code they ended up using to collect those stats:

```
module PumaThreadLogger

  def initialize *args
    ret = super *args
    Thread.new do
      while true

        # Every X seconds, write out what the state of this dyno is in a format that Librato understands.
        sleep 5

        thread_count = 0
        backlog = 0
        waiting = 0

        # I don't do the logging or string stuff inside of the mutex. I want to get out of there as fast as possible
        @mutex.synchronize {
          thread_count = @workers.size
          backlog = @todo.size
          waiting = @waiting
        }

        # For some reason, even a single Puma server (not clustered) has two booted ThreadPools.
        # One of them is empty, and the other is actually doing work
        # The check above ignores the empty one
        if (thread_count > 0)

          # It might be cool if we knew the Puma worker index for this worker, but that didn't look easy to me.
          # The good news: By using the PID we can differentiate two different workers on two different dynos with the same name
          # (which might happen if one is shutting down and the other is starting)
          source_name = "#{Process.pid}"

          # If we have a dyno name, prepend it to the source to make it easier to group in the log output
          dyno_name = ENV['DYNO']
          if (dyno_name)
            source_name="#{dyno_name}."+source_name
          end
          msg = "source=#{source_name} "

          msg += "sample#puma.backlog=#{backlog} sample#puma.active_connections=#{thread_count - waiting} sample#puma.total_threads=#{thread_count}"
          Rails.logger.info msg
        end
      end
    end
    ret
  end
end

module Puma
  class ThreadPool
    prepend PumaThreadLogger
  end
end
```

This code contains logic that is specific to heroku, but the core of collecting the `@workers.size` and logging it will work in any environment.