# How to know the number of active threads in Puma

Tags: shell, monitoring, puma

I am trying to see the number of active puma threads on my server.

I can not see it through `ps`:

```
$ ps aux | grep puma
healthd   2623  0.0  1.8 683168 37700 ?        Ssl  May02   5:38 puma 2.11.1 (tcp://127.0.0.1:22221) [healthd]  
root      8029  0.0  0.1 110460  2184 pts/0    S+   06:34   0:00 grep --color=auto puma
root     18084  0.0  0.1  56836  2664 ?        Ss   May05   0:00 su -s /bin/bash -c puma -C /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/pumaconf.rb webapp
webapp   18113  0.0  0.8  83280 17324 ?        Ssl  May05   0:04 puma 2.16.0 (unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock) [/]                                                               
webapp   18116  3.5  6.2 784992 128924 ?       Sl   May05 182:35 puma: cluster worker 0: 18113 [/]
```

As in the configuration I have:

```
threads 8, 32
```

I was expecting to see at least 8 puma threads?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @knagode I have open a bounty for this question and it got a lot of attention, can you check the answers and vote the ones you think are more helpful? it will help me to chose the valid answer.

Answer (score 19):

To quickly answer the question, the number of threads used by a
process running on a given PID, can be obtained using the
following :

```
% ps -h -o nlwp <pid>
```

This will just return you the total number of threads used by the
process. The option `-h` removes the headers and the option `-o nlwp`
formats the output of `ps` such that it only outputs the *Number of Light Weight Processes* (NLWP) or threads. Example, when only a single process `puma` is running and its PID is obtained with `pgrep`, you get:

```
% ps -h -o nlwp $(pgrep puma)
   4
```

**What is the difference between process, thread and light-weight process?**

This question has been answered already in various places
[See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484355/what-the-difference-between-lightweight-process-and-thread) and [the excellent geekstuff
article](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/11/linux-process-and-threads/)]. The quick, short and ugly version is :

- a *process* is essentially any running instance of a program.
- a *thread* is a flow of execution of the process. A process
  containing multiple execution-flows is known as multi-threaded
  process and shares its resources amongst its threads (memory,
  open files, io, ...). The Linux kernel has no knowledge of what
  `threads` are and only knows processes. In the past,
  multi-threading was handled on a user level and not kernel
  level. This made it hard for the kernel to do proper process
  management.
- Enter *lightweight processes* (LWP). This is essentially the
  answer to the issue with threads. Each thread is considered to
  be an LWP on kernel level. The main difference between a
  process and an LWP is that the LWP shares resources. In other words, an *Light Weight Process* is kernel-speak for what users call a *thread*.

**Can `ps` show information about threads or LWP's?**

The `ps` command or *process status* command provides information
about the currently running processes including their corresponding
LWPs or threads. To do this, it makes use of the `/proc` directory
which is a virtual filesystem and regarded as the control and
information centre of the kernel. [See [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/262177/how-does-the-ps-command-work)].

By default `ps` will not give you any information about the LWPs,
however, adding the option `-L` and `-m` to the command generally does
the trick.

> **`man ps :: THREAD DISPLAY`**
>
> ```
>    H      Show threads as if they were processes.
>    -L     Show threads, possibly with LWP and NLWP columns.
>    m      Show threads after processes.
>    -m     Show threads after processes.
>    -T     Show threads, possibly with SPID column.
> ```

For a single process `puma` with pid given by `pgrep puma`

```
% ps -fL $(pgrep puma)
UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
kvantour  2160  2876  2160  0    4 15:22 pts/39   Sl+    0:00 ./puma
kvantour  2160  2876  2161 99    4 15:22 pts/39   Rl+    0:14 ./puma
kvantour  2160  2876  2162 99    4 15:22 pts/39   Rl+    0:14 ./puma
kvantour  2160  2876  2163 99    4 15:22 pts/39   Rl+    0:14 ./puma
```

however, adding the `-m` option clearly gives a nicer overview. This
is especially handy when multiple processes are running with the same
name.

```
% ps -fmL $(pgrep puma)
UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
kvantour  2160  2876     -  0    4 15:22 pts/39   -      0:44 ./puma
kvantour     -     -  2160  0    - 15:22 -        Sl+    0:00 -     
kvantour     -     -  2161 99    - 15:22 -        Rl+    0:14 -     
kvantour     -     -  2162 99    - 15:22 -        Rl+    0:14 -     
kvantour     -     -  2163 99    - 15:22 -        Rl+    0:14 -
```

In this example, you see that process `puma` with PID 2160 runs with 4
threads (NLWP) having the ID's 2160--2163. Under `STAT` you see two different values `Sl+` and 'Rl+'. Here the `l` is an indicator for `multi-threaded`. `S` and `R` stand for *interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)* and respectively *running*. So we see that 3 of the 4 threads are running at 99% CPU and one thread is sleeping.
You also see the total accumulated CPU time (44s) while a single thread only runs for 14s.

Another way to obtain information is by directly using the format
specifiers with `-o` or `-O`.

> **`man ps :: STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS`**
>
> ```
>    lwp    lightweight process (thread) ID of the dispatchable
>           entity (alias spid, tid).  See tid for additional
>           information.  Show threads as if they were processes.
>    nlwp   number of lwps (threads) in the process.  (alias thcount).
> ```

So you can use any of `lwp`,`spid` or `tid` and `nlwp` or `thcount`.

If you only want to get the number of threads of a process called
`puma`, you can use :

```
% ps -o nlwp $(pgrep puma)
NLWP
   4
```

or if you don't like the header

```
% ps -h -o nlwp $(pgrep puma)
   4
```

You can get a bit more information with :

```
% ps -O nlwp $(pgrep puma)
PID   NLWP S TTY          TIME COMMAND
19304    4 T pts/39   00:00:00 ./puma
```

Finally, you can combine the flags with `ps aux` to list the threads.

```
 % ps aux -L
USER       PID   LWP %CPU NLWP %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
...
kvantour  1618  1618  0.0    4  0.0  33260  1436 pts/39   Sl+  15:17   0:00 ./puma
kvantour  1618  1619 99.8    4  0.0  33260  1436 pts/39   Rl+  15:17   0:14 ./puma
kvantour  1618  1620 99.8    4  0.0  33260  1436 pts/39   Rl+  15:17   0:14 ./puma
kvantour  1618  1621 99.8    4  0.0  33260  1436 pts/39   Rl+  15:17   0:14 ./puma
...
```

**Can `top` show information about threads or LWP's?**

`top` has the option to show threads by hitting `H` in the interactive mode or by launching top with `top -H`. The problem is that it lists the threads as processes (similar to `ps -fH`).

```
% top
top - 09:42:10 up 17 days, 3 min,  1 user,  load average: 3.35, 3.33, 2.75
Tasks: 353 total,   3 running, 347 sleeping,   3 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 75.5 us,  0.6 sy,  0.5 ni, 22.6 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.8 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16310772 total,  8082152 free,  3662436 used,  4566184 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4194300 total,  4194300 free,        0 used. 11363832 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  868 kvantour  20   0   33268   1436   1308 S 299.7  0.0  46:16.22 puma
 1163 root      20   0  920488 282524 258436 S   2.0  1.7 124:48.32 Xorg
 ...
```

Here you see that `puma` runs at about 300% CPU for an accumulated time of 46:16.22. There is, however, no indicator that this is a threaded process. The only indicator is the CPU usage, however, this could be below 100% if 3 threads are "sleeping"? Furthermore, the status flag states `S` which indicates that the first thread is asleep. Hitting `H` give you then

```
% top -H
top - 09:48:30 up 17 days, 10 min,  1 user,  load average: 3.18, 3.44, 3.02
Threads: 918 total,   5 running, 910 sleeping,   3 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 75.6 us,  0.2 sy,  0.1 ni, 23.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16310772 total,  8062296 free,  3696164 used,  4552312 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4194300 total,  4194300 free,        0 used. 11345440 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  870 kvantour  20   0   33268   1436   1308 R 99.9  0.0  21:45.35 puma
  869 kvantour  20   0   33268   1436   1308 R 99.7  0.0  21:45.43 puma
  872 kvantour  20   0   33268   1436   1308 R 99.7  0.0  21:45.31 puma
 1163 root      20   0  920552 282288 258200 R  2.0  1.7 124:52.05 Xorg 
  ...
```

Now we see only 3 threads. As one of the Threads is "sleeping", it is way down the bottom as `top` sorts by CPU usage.

In order to see all threads, it is best to ask top to display a specific `pid` (for a single process):

```
% top -H -p $(pgrep puma)
top - 09:52:48 up 17 days, 14 min,  1 user,  load average: 3.31, 3.38, 3.10
Threads:   4 total,   3 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 75.5 us,  0.1 sy,  0.2 ni, 23.6 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.7 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16310772 total,  8041048 free,  3706460 used,  4563264 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4194300 total,  4194300 free,        0 used. 11325008 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  869 kvantour  20   0   33268   1436   1308 R 99.9  0.0  26:03.37 puma
  870 kvantour  20   0   33268   1436   1308 R 99.9  0.0  26:03.30 puma
  872 kvantour  20   0   33268   1436   1308 R 99.9  0.0  26:03.22 puma
  868 kvantour  20   0   33268   1436   1308 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 puma
```

When you have multiple processes running, you might be interested in hitting `f` and toggle `PGRP` on. This shows the Group PID of the process. (PID in ps where PID in top is LWP in ps).

**How do I get the thread count without using `ps` or `top`?**

The file `/proc/$PID/status` contains a line stating how many threads
the process with PID `$PID` is using.

```
% grep Threads /proc/19304/status
Threads:        4
```

**General comments**

- It is possible that you do not find the process of another user
  and therefore cannot get the number of threads that process is using. This could be due to the [mount options of `/proc/`](https://superuser.com/questions/199044/is-it-possible-to-hide-a-process-from-the-listing-of-ps-or-top-on-linux) (hidepid=2).

**Used example program:**

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
char c = 0;
#pragma omp parallel shared(c)   {
    int i = 0;
    if (omp_get_thread_num() == 0) {
      printf("Read character from input : ");
      c = getchar();
    } else {
      while (c == 0) i++;
      printf("Total sum is on thread %d : %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);
    }
  }
}
```

compiled with `gcc -o puma --openmp`

Answer (score 6):

If you are just looking for number of threads that are spawned by the process, you can see the number of `task` folders created under `/proc/[pid-of-process]/task` because each thread creates a folder under this path. So counting the number of folders would be sufficient.

In fact the `ps` utility itself reads the information from this path, a file `/proc/[PID]/cmdline` which is represented in a more readable way.

From [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html)

> `/proc` is very special in that it is also a virtual file-system. It's sometimes referred to as a process information pseudo-file system. It doesn't contain 'real' files but run-time system information (e.g. system memory, devices mounted, hardware configuration, etc). For this reason it can be regarded as a control and information center for the kernel. In fact, quite a lot of system utilities are simply calls to files in this directory.

All you need to get the PID of the process `puma`, use `ps` or any utility of your choice

```
ps aux | awk '/[p]uma/{print $1}'
```

or more directly use [pidof(8) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof) which gets you the PID directly given the process name as input

```
pidof -s puma
```

Now that you have the PID to count the number of `task/` folders your process had created use the `find` command

```
find /proc/<PID>/task -maxdepth 1 -type d -print | wc -l
```

Answer (score 3):

`ps aux | grep puma` will give you list of process for only puma. You need to find out , how many threads are running by the particular Process. May be this will help you:

`ps -T -p 2623`

You need to provide process id, for which you want to find out number of threads. Make sure you are providing accurate process id.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ps` and `wc` to count `puma` threads:

```
ps --no-headers -T -C puma | wc -l
```

The string "*puma*" can be replaced as desired.  Example, count `bash` threads:

```
ps --no-headers -T -C bash | wc -l
```

On my system that outputs:

```
9
```

---

The code in the question, `ps aux | grep puma`, has a few `grep` related problems:

1. It returns `grep --color=auto puma`, which isn't a `puma` thread at all.
2. Similarly any util or command with the string "*puma*", *e.g.* a util called `notpuma`, would be matched by `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

I found "htop" to be an excellent solution.  Just toggle "tree view" and you can view each puma-worker and the threads under that worker.

Answer (score 1):

Number of puma threads for each worker:

```
ps aux | awk '/[p]uma/{print $2}' | xargs ps -h -o nlwp
```

Sample output:

```
   7
  59
  59
  61
  59
  60
  59
  59
  59
```